# WebRequest timeout exception c#

Tags: c#, stream, webrequest

I have a web request with a timeout of 5000 milliseconds. I have this because the server probably could don't give any response. All works fine, but when the timeout is reached, it throws me an exception "InternalException: System error." I post my code below, hope it helps, thanks!

```
try
{                        
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://xxxx.com/xxx"); 
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.EnableSsl = true;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx@xxxx", "xxxxxxx");
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return (true);
    };
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\xxxx");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    stream.Close();
    request.Timeout = 5000;
    Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    actBarLenght = buffer.Length;
    reqStream.Flush();
    reqStream.Close();

    File.Delete("H:\\xxxxx");

    uploading = false;
}
catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
```

The error I have:

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=System error.
  Source=ConfigurationApp
  StackTrace:
   at ConfigurationApp.SysTimeDate.ftpSend() in C:\xxx\SysTimeDate.cs:line 2177
   at xxx.frmConfiguration.button30_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\xxx\frmConfiguration.cs:line 3583
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at ConfigurationApp.Program.Main() in C:\xxx\Program.cs:line 20

Inner Exception 1:
InternalException: System error.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post full stack and error?

Comment: Btw, a time-out usually indicates an error, a dropped connection for example. In that case an exception is not uncommon.

Comment: What do you expect your code will do if it reaches the timeout limit?

Comment: @Stefan I post the error

Comment: @rene I want to continue with the program as nothing hoppens, I mean, it tries to download, if it doesn't have an answer, continue without other tasks without downloading the file

Comment: What is the code at `C:\xxx\SysTimeDate.cs:line 2177` ?

Comment: Remove `{ throw ex; }` then,

Comment: @HenkRoux is the catch line of the code I have posted.

Comment: @stuartd that's fix the problem?

Comment: @stuartd I mean, is that the correct answer? I thought that the timeout makes it stops receiving data if it reaches the timeout time.

Comment: @Imrik ok, so how far in your `try { }` do you get before the exception is thrown? Do you get to `File.OpenRead(C:\...)`? Do you get to `File.Delete(H:\..)` ? Also, why do you delete from a different location that you read from?

Comment: @helloserve is the same location, I copied wrong, sorry. It breaks at getrequeststream line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @stuartd from comments. If "all works fine", and your file *is* uploaded, but the server implementation doesn't follow FTP standards and responds incorrectly or not at all, then the only thing you *can* do is to swallow the timeout exception, don't throw, and move on.

However, instead of catching the general `Exception`, try and catch the most specific exception type that you can (e.g. `WebException`), and then still catch the general exception type after that so that you can log and report on *other* errors.

Comment: That is the fix I do. Forgive the delay in answering